# Provided a command in writing a class which can be used by the user

Tags: documentclass-writing

Suppose that I try to write a `test_cls` class, in which I want to provided a command `\inst`, that can be used by the user and also in the class doc itself.

The class file named `test_cls.cls` looks like:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{test_cls}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{test_cls}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\inst}[1]{\def\inst@value{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\theauthor}{\inst@value\\\@author}

\LoadClass{article}
```

And the `test_cls.tex` is

```
\documentclass{test_cls}
%\inst{test}
\author{tester}
\begin{document}
  \theauthor
\end{document}
```

The problem is this can't work and hint me that the command `\inst@value` is not defined.

I can solve this problem by add the default value by

```
\AtEndOfPackage{
  %for the default value
  \inst{default}
}
```

But don't know is there any other better way?